# join two columns and show ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just want to show two columns in one.
I have cod and number in Product table.
I want to show cod + number in the same column and add 0 before. For example: cod AAA, number 12. Then AAA012 must be show. If the number is less than 3 "characters"(xxx), a "cero" must be added.
I have something like this but doesn't work

```
def to_label
  "#{cod}-#{number}"
end
```

UPDATE

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>  
  <td><%= item.cod %></td>  
  <td><%= item.num %></td>
```

...
In this section you can see those two fields. I need show in one column and add ceros, depending the number (12, 012 / 1, 001). Hope you understand..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`rjust`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-rjust) to pad your number with zeros.

```
def to_label
  "#{cod}#{number.to_s.rjust(3, '0')}"
end
```

EDIT:

Or if you like a more concise version without `rjust`:

```
def to_label
  "#{cod}#{'%03d' % number}"
end
```

Comment: @ingzane, you're welcome. Please mark my response as 'accepted' if it answered your question to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should simply call `to_label` method:

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
  <%= item.to_label %>
  <!-- ... -->
<% end %>
```

Comment: Tks M. Have you any idea how to add a (zeros) on the left. For example..you have codAAA and number 12, must be show as AAA012.Tks again!

Comment: The method rjust  can help you, string_variable.rjust(3, '0')

Comment: Tks Joel, rjust interesting method